# Stored Procedure is taking very long to complete

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures

We have a `csv` file with 2000 rows and a database `table1` about 2 million rows and another `table2` with 60000 rows.

We need to query from `table1` based on parameters from the csv file, so each row in `csv` should execute one select query. Initially we tried to execute the following query within a `for loop` in the application:

```
SELECT table1.c1, table1.c2, ST_Distance_Sphere(point(csv.c2[i], csv.c3[i]), point(table1.c3, table1.c4))*0.2 AS length, table1.c5 FROM table1 
WHERE table1.c1 IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT table2.c1 FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table2.c1=table1.c1 
   WHERE table2.c2=1 AND table2.c3 BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
   ) HAVING length < csv.c4[i] 
AND table1.c5 BETWEEN date("start_date") 
AND date("end_date") ORDER BY table.c1
```

the `csv.c1[i]` `i` is actually the loop index. Because of the 2000 round trips to MySQL server, it takes a long time to complete this. It takes about 16 hours just to get through the queries.

So, I wrote the SP below to avoid looping and simply call this SP so can do the looping in MySQL server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp() 
    BEGIN 
      DECLARE arg0 VARCHAR(255);
      DECLARE arg1 FLOAT;
      DECLARE arg2 FLOAT;
      DECLARE arg3 FLOAT;
      DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM csv_based_table;
      OPEN cur1; 
      read_loop: LOOP
         FETCH cur1 INTO arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3;
         SELECT col0, col1, ST_Distance_Sphere(point(arg1, arg2),point(col3,col4))*2 AS length, arg0 FROM important_table1 WHERE 
         col0 IN (
             SELECT DISTINCT c0 FROM important_table2 LEFT JOIN c0 ON col0 = c0 WHERE c1=1 and c2 BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000) 
         HAVING distance < arg3 AND col5 BETWEEN date("start_date") AND 
         date("end_date") ORDER BY arg0, col0;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE cur1;
    END;
```

So, instead of using the csv file, we create a database table for that csv file and run the above stored procedure. Problem is this turned out to be slower than the original 2000 iterations loop. In a test over 100 csv rows, for loop-based original solution finished in **317.6 seconds** while the stored procedure took **321.5 seconds** just for the SP itself. Why is this happening and how can I optimize this?

Comment: Do you have same select column and where condition like SELECT A FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE  COLUMN_NAME = 'VALUE' AND .....

Comment: yes that's right.

Comment: Then why not create a single SELECT statement with where clause like COLUMN_NAME IN ('ABC','CED','EDF',......) from for loop in your python code

Comment: I don't understand, can you write down some code hopefully using the same symbols I have used?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. While you've included a bunch of (pseudo) code, the meat is missing: table definitions, information about possible indexes, some sample data and actual verifiable code.

Comment: query = "SELECT somethings FROM something WHERE somecondition IN ("
    whereclus = ""
    for i in range(0, len(list_containing_csv_rows)):
      whereclus = whereclus +  name1 + ","
    query = query+whereclus+")"
    execute and fetch rows some thing like this

Comment: @IljaEverilä added more specific code and changed phrasing. Hopefully this will be clearer...